# Registration forms based on attribute - Django

Tags: python, django

I have extended the user model with AbstractBaseUser with specific attributes to differentiate account types - Job Seeker and Employer. I would like to have 2 separate registration & login forms for users - 1 for job seekers to login/register and 1 for employers to login/register. I am struggling to figure out the best approach to doing this. What's the best approach to setting up two forms and set the is_jobseeker to True when registering for a jobseeker account and is_employer to true when registering for an employer account?

I've included my models.py for reference if need.

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email           = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    # account types
    is_jobseeker    = models.BooleanField(_('Job Seeker'), default=True)
    is_employer     = models.BooleanField(_('Employer'), default=False)

    is_staff        = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser    = models.BooleanField(_('Site Admin'), default=False)

    # account activity
    is_active       = models.BooleanField(_('Active'), default=True)

    # personal fields
    first_name      = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, default='')
    last_name       = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, default='')

    # contact fields
    phone           = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True, default='')

    # location fields
    address         = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    city            = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    state           = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, default='')

    # other fields
    date_joined     = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Use ModelForm, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform

Comment: Okay, but how would i set the attribute of is_employer to true on submit of registration?

Comment: Use widgets, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/